# How to get characters in a String in Java Regardless of String size

Tags: java, string

Lets have this String for example:

```
"C:\Users\User\workspace\Iterator\src\Iterate_Choose.java"
"C:\Users\User\workspace\Iterator\src\testing.java"
```

How can I get the string just after src\ and before .java. The output should be like this:

```
Iterate_choose
testing
```

I tried looking for regex but cannot find one that matches this situation.

Comment: Why not simply substring from lastIndexOf("\\") to string length -1??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regexp or look for the positions of the relevant parts:

```
    int pos1 = s.indexOf("src\\");
    int pos2 = s.lastIndexOf(".java");
    String result = s.substring(pos1 + 4, pos2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use RegEx:

```
    String outStr = Pattern.compile(".+src\\([^.]+)\.java")
                           .matcher("...\src\Iterate_Choose.java")
                           .find() ? m.group(1) 
                                   : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions if you don't have to.

```
String getFileName(String path) {
    int lastSlashIndex = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
    int dotIndex = path.indexOf(".", lastSlashIndex);

    return path.substring(lastSlashIndex, dotIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring:

```
String s1 = "C:\Users\User\workspace\Iterator\src\Iterate_Choose.java";
String s = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf("\\"),s1.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Isn't it simple.